# vb.net: zooming in on mouse pointer with pixelation

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a colour picker in VB and I'm trying to show the pixels at mouse pointer inside of a picturebox. It works, but only once, as soon as I open the program. I would like it to be able to be started and stopped with a button and a key on the keyboard and for it to update whenever the mouse is moved (ideally every 5 milliseconds). I have attached the code that I have and some screenshots of what I mean.

I've tried using different loops, running it under a timer and making it activate with the enter key on the keyboard.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(10, 10)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

        Dim p As Point = MousePosition
        p.Offset(-2, 2)
        g.CopyFromScreen(p, New Point(0, 0), bmp.Size)

    End Using

    Dim w As Integer = PictureBox1.Width
    Dim h As Integer = PictureBox1.Height
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, w, h)

    Dim r As Rectangle
    r.X = w \ 2 - w \ 10
    r.Y = h \ 2 - h \ 10
    r.Width = w \ 5
    r.Height = h \ 5
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightGray, r)

End Sub
```

I've tried putting all this code into a repeating loop (and a timer), but the program enters break mode.

[image: https://ibb.co/5jBgnp2]

(the image shows what happens when I hover over an area, but the picturebox doesn't update when I move my mouse cursor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have assigned the event of PictureBox1_paint, and you said you have timer, so try to add this code for your timer:

```
'this will automatically call your PictureBox1_Paint
'Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
'    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(10, 10)
'    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
'End Sub

'this more better
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```